# Manipulate already running instance of excel in powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

Alright, so I opened a workbook from an instance of Internet Explorer started from powershell using:

```
$browser = new-object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$browser.navigate("url")
```

I downloaded/opened the workbook from the url but I want to manipulate it with the running script. I was wondering if I'm able to create a new com object from the process id:

```
(Get-Process  excel | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle  -like "*titleOFdownloadedEXCELwb*"}).id
```

would someone be able to point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: Don't worry about getting the excel instance. 
Create an instance of Excel.Application and it will automatically give you a running instance. Set visible to true on the application and enumerate the workbooks using app.workbooks collection and find your workbook

Comment: Thanks for replying, the thing is, the workbook is opened from the browser (downloaded in temp folder)  and then opened in excel. How would I go about enumerating the wb?

Comment: `$xl = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')`

Comment: Thank you dgorti and @sodawillow, I got it working now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$xl = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Excel.Ap‌​plication')
```

will target the active Excel instance (if existing).